# Can you change the boot order of a VMware ESXi EFI guest in a config file?

Tags: vmware-esxi

For VMware ESXi guests that are booted with a BIOS boot firmware it is possible to configure the boot order directly in the .vmx file of the guest, according to [this VMware kb article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2011654), by specifying these options:

```
bios.bootOrder = "ethernet5,ethernet2,hdd,cdrom,floppy"
bios.hddOrder = "scsi2:2,scsi0:1,ide1:0"
```

Q: Is something similar possible if the guest is booted with an EFI firmware?

I know I can change the boot order by accessing the EFI setup screen, but I would like to have something that can be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't found a way to directly change the EFI boot order, a workaround is to configure the EFI boot order from the GUI, and then create a backup of the `vm.nvram` file.
Later you can restore the `vm.nvram` file from a backup that has the EFI boot order you need.